# Probability Question, choosing a favorable case

Tags: probability

I was recently asked this question in an interview, to which I could not answer correctly hence posting it here.

I am basketball player, and I can win if I (i) score 3 times out of 5  OR (ii)6 times out of 10

I get to choose the condition (i) or (ii) to win, which one should I choose so that result is in my favor.

The way I thought about it so far is if ***p*** be the probability of scoring , then if ***p*** is lower than 0.5, I would choose (i) where as if its higher than 0.5, I would choose (ii). This is more of logical sense as if I scoring consistently, I would have to give more number of tries, but If I score less frequently, I have to rely on the chance factor, that can happen if I do it less number of times. But this reasoning is not concrete.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ideas are correct, except that there is no reason why the cutoff point should be $0.5$.

You need to find $p$ such that
$$\sum_{k=3}^5\binom5kp^k(1-p)^{5-k}=\sum_{k=6}^{10}\binom{10}kp^k(1-p)^{10-k}$$
with $0<p<1$.  I can't see how to do this easily (after cancelling common factors of $p$ and $1-p$ you end up with a fourth degree equation), but Maple gives $p=0.6725$.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is generally correct.  If you want an atypical result, like needing 3 of 5 when your chance on one try is less than $\frac 12$, you want fewer total tries.  If you want a typical result, you want more tries.  Since the required success rate is $60\%$, you should expect to want to go for $3$ out of $5$ if your chance of scoring is less than $0.6$.

[This Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28sum%20%285%20choose%20n%29x%5En%281-x%29%5E%285-n%29%20for%20n%20from%203%20to%205%29-%28sum%20%2810%20choose%20n%29x%5En%281-x%29%5E%2810-n%29%20for%20n%20from%206%20to%2010%29%20x%20from%20.6%20to%20.8) shows that the transition actually happens around $p=0.67$.  Below that, go for $3$ of $5$.  The plot over the whole range is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20%28sum%20%285%20choose%20n%29x%5En%281-x%29%5E%285-n%29%20for%20n%20from%203%20to%205%29-%28sum%20%2810%20choose%20n%29x%5En%281-x%29%5E%2810-n%29%20for%20n%20from%206%20to%2010%29%20).  $x$ in these plots is your $p$ and $n$ is the number made.